# What length does font size refer to?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

What exactly is the size of a font?  Is there a certain length that must always be 10pt in a 10pt font?

Comment: The important measures  are \baselineskip, \ht\strutbox and \dp\strutbox, however they may not be the same as the font size.  (\Topskip tends to be.)

Answer (score 7):

No, the font size is an arbitrary length. It was traditionally the width of a capital M, but that does no longer hold for modern fonts. (Where "modern" includes pretty much every digital font ever created.)

For additional information and background, you might want to look at http://www.thomasphinney.com/2011/03/point-size/.

On the other hand, it isn't quite that easy because there actually is one character which by definition should be sized according to the fontsize: the "em Dash". The unit `em` is normally defined as the fontsize. So the current fontsize is always `1em`. (Technically TeX does not enforce that and would also allow fonts where `1em` is e.g. 90% of the fontsize, but normally that doesn't happen and it wouldn't fit to the traditional meaning of `em`.) Therefore the "em Dash" (which is a dash of width 1em, normally written in TeX as `---`) will always have a width of (at least almost) the fontsize.

This doesn't really fit the question though because it is kind of inversed: The size is not defined by the em-Dash, it is the em-Dash which is defined using the fontsize.

Comment: Does "traditional" also include (pretty much) every metal font ever created?

Comment: @Toothrot I think even for metal fonts the capital M convention didn't generally hold, but I do not know anything about that. For metal fonts, the fon-size had some meaning though: The height of the metal pieces corresponded to the fontsize.

Comment: although saying the font size is 1em can be misleading em is fontdimen6 which isn't always the font size as used in the font name, eg  cmtt10 is a "10pt font" but `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
\expandafter\show\the\font
\showthe\fontdimen6\font
\setbox0\hbox{\textemdash}\showthe\wd0
\end{document}`  shows that 1em is 10.45pt and an emdash is 5.25pt

Comment: Please see Peter Wilson's answer, which is far more accurate.

Answer (score 7):

In the days when type was cast on lead blocks the height of the block was the font size. The characters were placed within the blocks so that they were completely contained top to bottom. One font might have generally tall characters while another might have generally shorter characters but if they were on blocks, say 10pt high, each would be a 10pt font.

In other words the font size roughly indicates the actual height of the characters but does not define them.

When type was set the blocks were set in rows. If the rows were tightly packed then there would still be vertical space between adjacent rows of characters. Often, though, a thin piece of lead, say 2pt, was inserted between the rows thus leading to an arrangement termed like "10/12pt leaded" which is the typical LaTeX setting.

Comment: This is also the reason why font-size is (generally) a slightly smaller number than the line-height (i.e. nothing to do with width) as it should be exactly equal to the font-size plus the leading, as Peter hints at in the last paragraph.